# Making a column auto-increment when autoincrement doesn't work (Sqlalchemy, PostgreSQL)

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, psycopg2

I made a simple table using sqlalchemy.

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine  
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base  
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy import Table, Column, ForeignKey, MetaData, Sequence
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
from sqlalchemy import INTEGER, REAL, VARCHAR, TIMESTAMP, BOOLEAN, Integer
import psycopg2 as pg
import psycopg2.extras

db_string = "postgresql://someDBInfoString"
db = create_engine(db_string)
base = declarative_base()

Session = sessionmaker(db)    
session = Session()           

class Women(base):
    __tablename__ = "WOMEN"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(VARCHAR)
    man = relationship("Men", uselist=False, back_populates="woman")
```

I tried several ways as below to make the `id` column have `Serial` type or an equivalent of it that can autoincrement.

1) Setting it as PK

2) Adding `autoincrement=True` keyword arg

```
id = Column(Integer, autoincrement=True, primary_key=True)
```

3) Passing `Sequence`

```
id = Column(Integer, Sequence('seq_tramos_id', start=1, increment=1), primary_key=True)
```

But in every method, `id` column is set as a plain Integer type on DBMS and inserting a data through DBMS (Postgresql) requires manually including `id` along with the other value. Inserting a data with ORM using session as in `session.add(somestring)` is no problem as `id` is automatically set just as I intended. So this is a problem of how ORM-created table works on DBMS.

What else can I try?

edit : added import and detailed description

Comment: How do you mean they haven't worked?  If I create these ids via sqlalchemy then `\ds` shows sequences have been created in each case.

Comment: Are you using [postgresql+psycopg2](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/dialects/postgresql.html#module-sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.psycopg2)?

Comment: Have you created the table using a non-incrementing integer primary key before and now only modified the Python model definition? Also, *serial is not a real type* in that the column will have an integer type and a sequence default, as described in the docs: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL

Comment: @GordThompson Yes. I should have clarified.

Comment: @snakecharmerb Clarified on the post. I don't know what \ds is though.. Thank you.

Comment: @IljaEverilä I deleted a table for each try so that shouldn't have been the reason. I clarified the issue on the post. Thank you for the link.

Comment: "Inserting a data with ORM using session ... is no problem" sounds like it's working. Now you'd need to demonstrate how you're "inserting data through DBMS", because that seems to be the problematic part. The model you've presented in your question works as it should, so the problem is not yet reproducible. And as noted before, "But in every method, id column is set as a plain Integer type on DBMS" is the expected behaviour.

Comment: `\ds` is a command you can run in the `psql` console that lists sequences in the current database.  See also `\d <table>` which shows details of a table. Running these commands may help you understnd what is happening on the db side.